# How to find closest value, after adding values in column, not less than the actual value

Tags: excel-formula

I have these values in a column

- 10000
- 15000
- 25000
- 10000

My actual value is 30000, closest value would be 25000 I but want the value that is closest but isn't less than the actual value (30000), i.e. 35000 should be the answer.

I know how to find the closest value but not the value closest and greater than the actual value.

Sample formula to achieve the closest value.

```
=INDEX(MOD(INT((ROW($C$3:INDEX($C:$C, 2^ROWS($C$3:$C$10)))-1)/2^(TRANSPOSE(MATCH(ROW($C$3:$C$10), ROW($C$3:$C$10)))-1)), 2)*TRANSPOSE($C$3:$C$10), MATCH(MIN(ABS(MMULT(MOD(INT((ROW($C$3:INDEX($C:$C, 2^ROWS($C$3:$C$10)))-1)/2^(TRANSPOSE(MATCH(ROW($C$3:$C$10), ROW($C$3:$C$10)))-1)), 2), $C$3:$C$10)-$G$2)), ABS(MMULT(MOD(INT((ROW($C$3:INDEX($C:$C, 2^ROWS($C$3:$C$10)))-1)/2^(TRANSPOSE(MATCH(ROW($C$3:$C$10), ROW($C$3:$C$10)))-1)), 2), $C$3:$C$10)-$G$2), 0), 0)
```

[image: ScreenShot as requested]

Comment: How many values do you have in reality? Just four? If it's potentially much more than a formula-based solution will not be feasible. And I take it that you're allowed to use as many values as you like when forming the sum?

Comment: yes, it's just a sample, it is dynamic so the number of rows can be many. Also, I am ok with code-based solutions too. I just posted the formula to understand the problem.

Comment: @SumanKumar You are providing a brain teaser if you post such a "tapeworm" formula without further explanation and/or reproducible data examples/screen shots.

Comment: @T.M. screenshot added as per request.

Comment: @SumanKumar This is not reproducible if it is not clear which cell references refer to which cells, which is your "actual limit value" and why the formula should find 35000 as closest value if there is no sample data of 35000 in your screenshot

Comment: @T.M. C3:C10 are numbers, G1 is the actual value and the result can be obtained has the same number of data as the Numbers. It's actually a formula array. Instead of 25000, We need 35000. in result value. The above formula gets 25000 which is the closest value and I need the formula or code to find the closest but greater than the actual value.

Comment: @SumanKumar I can probably guess now roughly what you want, but cannot promise to understand the logic of this horrible "tapeworm" formula enough to solve it.  In any case, it will still take some time to break down the formula into meaningful parts. - Btw Which version of Excel are you using? Where did you get this formula, maybe you have a link to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=INDEX(MOD(INT((ROW($B$2:INDEX($B:$B,2^ROWS($B$2:$B$9)))-1)/2^(TRANSPOSE(MATCH(ROW($B$2:$B$9),ROW($B$2:$B$9)))-1)),2)*TRANSPOSE($B$2:$B$9),MATCH(MIN(IF((MMULT(MOD(INT((ROW($B$2:INDEX($B:$B,2^ROWS($B$2:$B$9)))-1)/2^(TRANSPOSE(MATCH(ROW($B$2:$B$9),ROW($B$2:$B$9)))-1)),2),$B$2:$B$9)-$E$1)>=0,MMULT(MOD(INT((ROW($B$2:INDEX($B:$B,2^ROWS($B$2:$B$9)))-1)/2^(TRANSPOSE(MATCH(ROW($B$2:$B$9),ROW($B$2:$B$9)))-1)),2),$B$2:$B$9)-$E$1,"")),MMULT(MOD(INT((ROW($B$2:INDEX($B:$B,2^ROWS($B$2:$B$9)))-1)/2^(TRANSPOSE(MATCH(ROW($B$2:$B$9),ROW($B$2:$B$9)))-1)),2),$B$2:$B$9)-$E$1,0),0)
```

Posting the answers for the one who might find this helpful. Thank You.